# streamlit_authentication unable to login into main app

Tags: python, authentication, streamlit

```
with open('./login_credentials.yaml') as file:
    config = yaml.load(file, Loader=SafeLoader)

authenticator = stauth.Authenticate(
    config['credentials'],
    config['cookie']['name'],
    config['cookie']['key'],
    config['cookie']['expiry_days'],
)

with open('./login_credentials.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(config, file, default_flow_style=False)


authenticator.login()



if st.session_state['authentication_status'] is False:
    st.error("Username/password is incorrect")

if st.session_state['authentication_status'] is None:
    st.warning("Please enter your username and password")

if st.session_state['authentication_status']:
    # plot function
    # @st.cache_data
    st.write(f'Welcome *{st.session_state["name"]}*')
    authenticator.logout()
    def plot(x,y,z):
      my code continues
```

I am trying to create a login authentication page for a streamlit application using streamlit authenticator, after which the user will be taken to the main app if login is successful but I keep getting this error
[image]